# Combine one table with each row from another

Tags: powerquery

I have two tables:

| Count |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |

and

| Temp |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

How can I combine them in order to get the following?

| Contx | Tempx |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |

I cannot do it manually since the last table has so many rows

Regards
B

Comment: This is known as a [cross join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/cross-join).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Temp query, add column, custom column with formula

```
= Count
```

Then use arrows atop the new column to expand to new rows

Alternatively, in Count query, add column, custom column, with formula

```
= Temp
```

Then use arrows atop the new column to expand to new rows

Alternatively, create a separate query that uses one of the above as the source and adds a column with =QueryName for the other query, and expand, like below

```
let Source = Temp,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Count),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Column1"}, {"CountX"})
in #"Expanded Custom"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

- create two Lists which equate to the two columns you want
- then combine the lists as columns

Copy the M-Code below into the Advanced Editor.

Please read the notes in the M Code, and step through the Applied Steps, to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Read in both tables
//be sure to change the table Name to the actual name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Count"]}[Content],
    Count = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Count", type text}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Temp"]}[Content],
    Temp = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{"Temp", Int64.Type}),

//create lists containing the contents of each column
    Temps = List.Repeat(Temp[Temp], Table.RowCount(Count)),
    Counts = List.Combine(List.Transform(Count[Count], each List.Repeat({_}, Table.RowCount(Temp)))),

//combine the two lists as two columns
    tbl = Table.FromColumns({Counts,Temps},{"Contx","Tempx"})
in
    tbl
```

[image]